# Issue with set object with condition

Tags: python-3.x

Unable to figure out why am I getting the output as "No" only in the below code.
Shouldn't it print "Yes" for those 2 set values

```
import re
import subprocess
from plumbum import local, cmd

s = subprocess.check_output(["opatch", "lsinventory"])
output = s.decode("utf-8")


patches = [27923320, 27547329, 21171382, 21463894, 18961555, 28432129]

patches_found = set(re.findall(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(map(str, patches)), output))
patches_missing = set(map(str, patches)) - patches_found


for item in patches_missing:
    if item in ["27923320", "27547329"]:
        print("Yes", item)
    else:
        print("No")
```

Comment: You're comparing strings to integers. All the elements in `patches_missing` are strings.

Comment: fix: `if item in ["27923320", "27547329"]:`

Answer (score 0):

The items `27923320` and `27547329` in the list `patches` are integers, while `"27923320"` and `"27547329"` are strings. This is what you want:

```
for item in patches_missing:
    if item in [27923320, 27547329]:
        print("Yes", item)
    else:
        print("No")
```